# How to Dexie.js call in service Worker

Tags: javascript, import, service-worker, call, dexie

I can not call the Dexie.js file in service worker using import scripts and I get a Failed to execute error.
Is there another way to call?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.